# CheckMark Index issue for multiple tables

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my project structure in Storyboards:

Navigation View Controller ------> Main View Controller ------> 2 Child View Controllers

Each of the two Child View Controllers has a separate Table and View Controller.

The code below is working absolutely fine, but the problem I am facing is that lets say I select index 2 in this Table (a checkmark image will appear): it will take me to the main ViewController, but then from the main ViewController if I tap a button to navigate to the another child view, that child view opens with a checkmark image already at index 2 (and vice versa).

Here is the Code of one of my ChildViewControllers:

```
#import "MainVC"
#import "ChildVC"
@interface ChildVC ()
@end

@implementation ChildVC

NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableArr =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"Other",nil];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Select Language";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 30)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    label.text = [tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.tag = 1;
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0f/255.0f green:111.0f/255.0f blue:182.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coloredCheckmark.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{    
    lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadData];

    // Here I am sending the Value of Selected Row to Main View Controller and storing in typelabel.text
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lbltemp = (UILabel *)[cell1 viewWithTag:1];
    _parent.typelabel.text = lbltemp.text;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 9;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell      forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if ([lastIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-checkMark.png"]];
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    }
} 

@end
```

Comment: Read this "Now below Code is ..... " and how to avoid this .

Comment: If you are positive you really have two separate child view controllers, maybe you just need to be calling "reload data" before they appear?

Comment: i am using different class another Child ViewController.

Comment: I think you may need to "reloadData" that you might be getting a cached value since you are using reusable cells...

Comment: where i need reload the data .

Comment: Are the two child VCs different classes (or one inherits from the other)? Assuming they are and are separate instances, try moving the declaration of lastIndexPath into the @interface section.

Comment: Yes . two child VC's have different classes

Comment: When you navigate to the new view, try reloading the data then.